# What does it mean by this async Javascript server app error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, server

I was setting a weather app website that is connected to another site using a server, and asynchronous javascript was used, but after trying to run the code, an error reading "uncaught syntax error: unexpected end of input" in the last line in the app file...I don't understand what it means and therefore I don't know how to solve it

here's my app file code

```
/* Global Variables */
const apiKey = "726f360f99f8ed5ce834f19b2f632fd3"
// Create a new date instance dynamically with JS
let d = new Date();
let newDate = +d.getMonth()+1+'.'+ d.getDate()+'.'+ d.getFullYear();
const gen = document.querySelector("#generate");
gen.addEventListener("click", async() =>{
    const Zcode = document.querySelector("#zip").value;
    const feel = document.querySelector("#feelings").value;
    try {
    getTemp()
    .then(temp =>{
        const object = {
            date: newDate,
            temp: temp,
        }
        return DealingWithServer()
    })
    .then(data =>{
        UpdateSite(data)
    })
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
async function getTemp (){
    const res = await fetch (`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather=?zip=${zipCode}&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric`);
    const data= await res.json;
    const temp = data.main.temp
    return temp
}
async function DealingWithServer (){
    await fetch('/recieve', {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body:JSON.stringfy({
            date: newDate,
            temp: temp,
            feel: feel
        })
    });
    const Sres = await fetch('/get', {credentials: "same-origin"});
    const Sdata = await Sres.json()
    return (Sdata);
}
function UpdateSite (data)
```

and my server file code

```
// Setup empty JS object to act as endpoint for all routes
projectData = {};
const port = 3000;
// Require Express to run server and routes
const express= require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
// Start up an instance of app
const app=express()
/* Middleware*/
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Cors for cross origin allowance
app.use(cors())
// Initialize the main project folder
app.use(express.static('website'));
app.get("/get",(req, res) => {
    res.send(projectData)
})
app.post("/recieve", (req, res) => {
    projectData =req.body
    res.status(200)
})
// Setup Server
app.listen(3000,() =>{
    console.log("Server running");
})
```

Comment: If `function UpdateSite (data)` is the end of the file, that's your problem

Comment: You're missing the body of the `UpdateSite` function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you've not finished your `UpdateSite` function at the bottom. It should read something like this:

```
function UpdateSite (data) {
  // Do things to update the site
}
```

Since there is no function definition, the input (JavaScript code in this case) has ended unexpectedly - i.e. the parser was not expecting the input to end with `function UpdateSite (data)`